# Finding out from which initrd image current RedHat session has booted

Tags: redhat, grub, init

How can I find out from which initrd image in `/boot/` a RedHat system has been booted from, assuming that there are multiple entries in `/etc/grub.conf` with the same kernel but different `initrd-*.img` files? (`dmesg` doesn't show it and there is no link from `/initrd`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entries in your `grub.conf` are in fact identical then there's really no good way to tell.  If the `grub.conf` entries have slightly different kernel options, you could look at `/proc/cmdline` to see what options were used to boot the current kernel.

Comment: The kernel/`init` will also ignore anything that's not a valid option, so feel free to jam comment flags in there for debugging. (Don't leave them there in production.)

Comment: seems that adding a kernel parameter is the most practical solution.